# How to run Apache Airflow DAG as Unix user

Tags: hadoop, airflow

I installed Apache Airflow on my cluster using `root` account. I know it is bad practice, but it is only test environment. I created a simple DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dag = DAG('create_directory', description='simple create directory workflow', start_date=datetime(2017, 6, 1))

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='create_dir', bash_command='mkdir /tmp/airflow_dir_test', dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(task_id='create_file', bash_command='echo airflow_works > /tmp/airflow_dir_test/airflow.txt')

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

The problem is that when I run this job, the `root` user executes it. I tried to add `owner` parameter, but it doesn't work. Airflow says:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/create_directory.py] name 'user1' is not defined
```

My question is, how I can run Apache Airflow DAG using other user than root?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `run_as_user` parameter to [impersonate](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html?highlight=owner#impersonation) a unix user for any task:

```py
t1 = BashOperator(task_id='create_dir', bash_command='mkdir /tmp/airflow_dir_test', dag=dag, run_as_user='user1')
```

You can use `default_args` if you want to apply it to every task in the DAG:

```py
dag = DAG('create_directory', description='simple create directory workflow', start_date=datetime(2017, 6, 1), default_args={'run_as_user': 'user1'})

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='create_dir', bash_command='mkdir /tmp/airflow_dir_test', dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(task_id='create_file', bash_command='echo airflow_works > /tmp/airflow_dir_test/airflow.txt')
```

Note that the `owner` parameter is for something else, [multi-tenancy](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html?highlight=owner#multi-tenancy).