# Issue running Apache-airflow SnowflakeOperator tutorial example

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to get a simplified version [snowflake operator example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/snowflake.html#using-the-operator) to work, but triggering the DAG fails with error:

```
Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
```

The dag only has the 1st task running the CREATE_TABLE_SQL_STRING. It will run successfully via test  run: `airflow dags test sf_example_short 2021-10-10`
I can see the table is created in snowflake so connection appears fine and syntax must be okay.

But drop the table and trigger via airflow UI or via CLI:
`airflow dags trigger sf_example_short`  it fails w/vague error:
Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT

googling I’ve found suggestions to change scheduler_health_check_threshold, or [schedule_after_task_exectution](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14672), or [default_impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012321/how-to-run-apache-airflow-dag-as-unix-user), or [OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY](http://ttps://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12808), or [killed_task_cleanup_time](https://www.cnblogs.com/braveym/p/12516513.html)
but none of these fixed the issue

What am I missing?  TIA!

Log excerpt:

```
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,256] {taskinstance.py:1114} INFO - Executing <Task(SnowflakeOperator): snowflake_cre_tbl> on 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,261] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 73291 to run task
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,271] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'sf_example_short', 'snowflake_cre_tbl', '2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00', '--job-id', '222', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/sf_example_short.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/jp/b35mp4dj4qn3y35k491hrpg80000gn/T/tmppt5q2b8h', '--error-file', '/var/folders/jp/b35mp4dj4qn3y35k491hrpg80000gn/T/tmp83zp78uz']
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,274] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 222: Subtask snowflake_cre_tbl
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,276] {cli_action_loggers.py:66} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: [<function default_action_log at 0x10e288940>]
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,286] {settings.py:208} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 73291)
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,287] {settings.py:244} DEBUG - settings.prepare_engine_args(): Using NullPool
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,289] {taskinstance.py:618} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [None]> from DB
[2021-10-11 10:03:57,298] {taskinstance.py:656} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]>
[2021-10-11 10:04:02,296] {taskinstance.py:618} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2021-10-11 10:04:02,299] {taskinstance.py:656} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]>
[2021-10-11 10:04:02,305] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]> on host xxxxxxs-MacBook-Pro.local
[2021-10-11 10:04:02,307] {taskinstance.py:618} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2021-10-11 10:04:02,310] {taskinstance.py:656} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]>
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,302] {base_job.py:227} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,331] {taskinstance.py:684} DEBUG - Clearing XCom data
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,336] {taskinstance.py:691} DEBUG - XCom data cleared
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,350] {taskinstance.py:1251} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=sf_example_short
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=snowflake_cre_tbl
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,351] {__init__.py:146} DEBUG - Preparing lineage inlets and outlets
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,351] {__init__.py:190} DEBUG - inlets: [], outlets: []
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,352] {snowflake.py:119} INFO - Executing: CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE SF_SHORT_TEST (name VARCHAR(250), id INT);
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,356] {base.py:70} INFO - Using connection to: id: snowflake_conn. Host: https://***.snowflakecomputing.com/, Port: None, Schema: airflow1, Login: xxxxxxxxxxx, Password: ***, extra: {'account': '***', 'warehouse': 'DEMO_WH', 'database': 'AIRFLOW_SANDBOX', 'role': 'sysadmin'}
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,358] {connection.py:218} INFO - Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.4.1, Python Version: 3.8.12, Platform: macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,359] {connection.py:421} DEBUG - connect
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,359] {connection.py:656} DEBUG - __config
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,359] {connection.py:773} INFO - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,359] {connection.py:789} INFO - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,360] {converter.py:135} DEBUG - use_numpy: False
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,360] {connection.py:570} DEBUG - REST API object was created: ***.snowflakecomputing.com:443
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,361] {auth.py:129} DEBUG - authenticate
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,362] {auth.py:156} DEBUG - assertion content: *********
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,362] {auth.py:160} DEBUG - account=***, user=xxxxxxxxxxx, database=AIRFLOW_SANDBOX, schema=airflow1, warehouse=DEMO_WH, role=sysadmin, request_id=***
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,362] {auth.py:193} DEBUG - body['data']: {'CLIENT_APP_ID': 'PythonConnector', 'CLIENT_APP_VERSION': '2.4.1', 'SVN_REVISION': None, 'ACCOUNT_NAME': '***', 'LOGIN_NAME': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'CLIENT_ENVIRONMENT': {'APPLICATION': 'PythonConnector', 'OS': 'Darwin', 'OS_VERSION': 'macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.8.12', 'PYTHON_RUNTIME': 'CPython', 'PYTHON_COMPILER': 'Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)', 'OCSP_MODE': 'FAIL_OPEN', 'TRACING': 10, 'LOGIN_TIMEOUT': 120, 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT': None}, 'SESSION_PARAMETERS': {'CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY': 900, 'CLIENT_PREFETCH_THREADS': 4}}
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,363] {retry.py:230} DEBUG - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,364] {retry.py:230} DEBUG - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,364] {network.py:950} DEBUG - Active requests sessions: 1, idle: 0
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,365] {network.py:650} DEBUG - remaining request timeout: 120, retry cnt: 1
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,365] {network.py:638} DEBUG - Request guid: ***
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,366] {network.py:794} DEBUG - socket timeout: 60
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,405] {local_task_job.py:151} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,405] {taskinstance.py:618} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,410] {taskinstance.py:656} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: sf_example_short.snowflake_cre_tbl 2021-10-11T15:01:09+00:00 [running]>
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,411] {taskinstance.py:1867} DEBUG - Task Duration set to 10.174875
[2021-10-11 10:04:07,411] {taskinstance.py:1505} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=sf_example_short, task_id=snowflake_cre_tbl, execution_date=20211011T150109, start_date=20211011T150357, end_date=20211011T150407
```

abbreviated system info:

```
Apache Airflow version                | 2.1.3                                              
executor               | SequentialExecutor                                 
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler  
System info
OS              | Mac OS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake       | 1.1.0
```

Comment: You likely run out of memory. But this is a wild guess. Check your resources.

Comment: hmm... wouldn't there be 503 error or the webserver shut down or something if there was a memory issue?

Comment: It can be anything. Depending who and how lacks memory (or other resources), you might have completely different errors. Again - this was a wild guess. It's always your responsibility to check for resources when you run programs - in any computer program when you run out resources, you might simply not have time or possibility to react to it, and what happens, depends on mutliple factors which are usually out-of-control of the program, and usually managed somehow by deployment.